How can I copy the corresponding table header(th) enty to their table cell(td) attr in css?
i need to copy the corresponding from table header entry to their table cell attr data-label in pure css. i dont need jquery.
i tried below in jquery. but i need in css example. Please give some example in pure html and css.
var $th = $("thead th");
var $tr = $("tbody tr");
$tr.each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('data-label', $th.eq(index).text());
    });
});


Do you mean vanilla JavaScript? Do you want your JavaScript code converted, so it doesn't use jQuery? Does your current code work as expected?

I'm guessing you want to use this with content: attr(data-label) to display appropriate "labels" in a mobile view, or something like that? CSS can not "copy" attribute values to different elements, and you can not use attr to access attributes on other elements than the one the selector targets, either.

This should work for you.  It uses the content: attr(data-label) ": " .  You can simply set the data-label attibute on every td


    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    td:before {
        content: attr(data-label) ": ";
        font-weight: bold;
    }
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Header 1">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
            <td data-label="Header 2">Row 1, Cell 2</td>
            <td data-label="Header 3">Row 1, Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="Header 1">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
            <td data-label="Header 2">Row 2, Cell 2</td>
            <td data-label="Header 3">Row 2, Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>




Mippy Thanks for the response. in the td element i am not give attributes of data-label="Header 1" like. but it automatically get from th content value and append into every td attr of data-label. is it possible in css. pls give example

@karthickbalakrishnan I do not believe it is possible in pure CSS.  CSS is not a scripting language, or a programming language at all for that manner, and is very limited in what it can do.
